# Why is it correct to say "to negate a double"?

Tags: word-choice, programming, computing

In programming you can *negate a double*. At least Google hits tend to that, but there are, though, a lot of hits for *invert a double*.

While the definition of *to invert* is clear

> [to invert](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/invert):
>
> to change the normal position of something, especially by turning it upside down or by arranging it in the opposite order

the definition of *to negate* seems to have a bit different meaning

> [to negate](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/negate):
>
> 1 to stop something from having any effect
>
> 2 to state that something does not exist

Other dictionaries like [merriam-wesbster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negate) back that up:

> to deny the existence or truth of
>
> to cause to be ineffective or invalid

Having said that I wonder why there are so many Google hits for *to negate a double*. We neither make it invalid nor we cease its existence.

I found one definition that goes into the direction of turning a value to its opposite but the definition fits more to a boolean than a double because *NOT 5* is unequal to *MINUS 5*.

> Computer Science: To perform the machine logic operation NOT gate. <sup>[thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/negate)</sup>

But the noun *negation* fits at all:

> [negation](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/negation):
>
> the exact opposite of something; the act of causing something not to exist or to become its opposite

So, why do we *negate a double* instead of *invert a double*?

Comment: Can you give a full sentence and the expected meaning? I'm having a hard time coming up with a context where this would mean something. Is it, "I need to find the negation of this number, in my code, it's a double precision floating point, so I need __to negate a double__." But you wouldn't say in the same context 'invert a double'. Instead of the phrase out of syntactic context, give a full sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mathematics, the *negation* of *x* is *−x*, while the *inverse* of *x* is 1/*x*. You shouldn't necessarily expect the meaning of terms used mathematically to correspond exactly to the ordinary English meaning of the terms.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. You're absolutely right. I think I suffered from a tunnel vision.